# Open windows store in a windows phone silverlight app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone, windows-store

I'm using silverlight to build apps for windows phone 7, 8.0 and 8.1

I have an URI in my code that contains `ms-windows-store:PDP?PFN=SupportingComputersInc.Fhotoroom_pxc4cxt3rds1p`

I'm trying to open the windows store to this specific app.

I found this code:

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

But it is just opening xbox music. Then, I found that:

```
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
options.PreferredApplicationPackageFamilyName = "SupportingComputersInc.Fhotoroom_pxc4cxt3rds1p";
options.PreferredApplicationDisplayName = "Fhotoroom app";
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);
```

But when I run this code I get a not implemented exception.

Is there another way to open the windows store on windows phone? Am I doing something bad here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone provides special launchers that should do the trick, for example to show a certain app's detail page in Store:

```
MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = "INSERT_APP_ID";
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

For a summary of what else is possible (e.g., show the store's search result page for certain search key words) see [Launchers for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394001%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you it does exactly what I want. I have one problem remaining. The ms-windows-store link that I posted is the only information that I have. It could also change (it is downloaded by my app)
I can't have the content identifier. Is there any way to do my stuff just with the informations I have ?

Comment: Well, the `MarketplaceDetailTask` is meant to advertise your _own_ apps. I don't think there is a way to transform the package family name of foreign apps to the ContentIdentifier.

Maybe the nearest you could get is remove publisher name and suffix from the package family name (e.g. retrieve "Fhotoroom" assuming this is the app's title), and open the store's search like:

`MarketplaceSearchTask task = new MarketplaceSearchTask
{
 SearchTerms = "Fhotoroom",
 ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications
};
task.Show();`

With a bit of luck, the desired app is first in the search results...

Comment: Searching in the store is a pretty good idea but I finally asked to the server-side guys to give me the unique marketplace ID instead of the PFN.
Thank you for your help.